# dynamically added imageviews which one is clicked on?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout which I fill with imageviews everytime the user takes a picture with the camera. So these imageviews are added dynamically.

To each of these imageviews I attached an OnClick event to open the picture and show it in another imageview in another activity.

Each imageview has a tag containing an arraylist item with the bitmap information.

The OnClick event:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
iv.setLayoutParams(params);
iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
iv.setTag(pli);
iv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
lvp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    PhotoList pli = (PhotoList) arg0.getTag();
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PhotoActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("photo", pli.Photo);
        i.putExtra("PhotoId", pli.id);
    startActivity(i);
}
});

lvp.addView(iv);
```

Obviously the line with arg0.getTag() is not working.
Variable arg0 is of the linearlayout, but I need the clicked on imageview.

How do I detect wich imageview in the linearlayout was clicked on?

rg,
Eric

Comment: "Obviously the line with arg0.getTag() is not working".  How do you know?

Comment: the tag is empty, probably because that would be the tag of the linear layout and not of the imageview.

Comment: Could you supply us with the code where you set the tag as well? That would be very meaningful since the tag is null...

Comment: The tag for the imageview is set, that I checked. The problem is getting to it after a click on it. The OnClick event only supplies the View (a linear layout) where the imageview is a child in. I can itterate through all the children in the layout, but I can't compare it to anything to get the right one.

Comment: Please show the code where you set the onClick listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `OnClickListener` to the parent `LinearLayout` instead of the `ImageView`.

Instead of this:

```java
lvp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Use this:

```java
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        ...
    }
});
```